# Preserve single/double quotes around value after interpolation and escape dollar($) sign

Tags: linux, bash, docker-compose, ansible, string-interpolation

I have docker-compose file and try to provide environment variable like this:

```
    environment:
      {{ envs | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | indent(width=6) }}
```

Overall it's fine except one env var `SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: $2b$10$J82IHSFuwneniWNTrkn8RO2N9Gjvi3juBa805IGyqR/y/w0as29VS` which contains $ in its value and other special characters. $ causes an bash interpolation issue when I try to run services, because it tried to substitute variable which doesn't exist.  How to wrap this value into single quotas and escape $ sign?

What I tried already:

- `SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: "{{ spring_security_user_password | password_hash('bcrypt', rounds=10) }}"` -> `$2b$10$J82IHSFuwneniWNTrkn8RO2N9Gjvi3juBa805IGyqR/y/w0as29VS`
- `SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: '"{{ spring_security_user_password | password_hash('bcrypt', rounds=10) }}"'` -> `'"$2b$10$J82IHSFuwneniWNTrkn8RO2N9Gjvi3juBa805IGyqR/y/w0as29VS"'` no idea why it preserved both ' and "
- `SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: "{{ spring_security_user_password | password_hash('bcrypt', rounds=10) | quote }}"` -> `'''$2b$10$J82IHSFuwneniWNTrkn8RO2N9Gjvi3juBa805IGyqR/y/w0as29VS'''` not idea why it add triple '
- `SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: " {{ spring_security_user_password | password_hash('bcrypt', rounds=10) }} "` -> `' $2b$10$J82IHSFuwneniWNTrkn8RO2N9Gjvi3juBa805IGyqR/y/w0as29VS '` yoohoo I wrapped it into ', but it added extra whitespace - why?

How can I get value like this `SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: '$$2b$$10$$J82IHSFuwneniWNTrkn8RO2N9Gjvi3juBa805IGyqR/y/w0as29VS'` $ escapped using $ and literal wrapped using '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another more reliable solution using jinja2 script:

```
    environment:
{% for name, value in envs.items() %}
{%  if value is string %}
{%    if not value.startswith('\'') and not value.startswith('"') %}
      {{ name }}: '{{ value | replace('$', '$$') }}'
{%    else %}
      {{ name }}: {{ value | replace('$', '$$') }}
{%    endif %}
{%  else %}
      {{ name }}: {{ value }}
{%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

which also does the work

Answer (score 0):

I found dirty workaround

`{{ envs | to_nice_json | regex_replace('\\$', '$$') | from_json | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | indent(width=6) }}`

It escapes $ only but it's enough to make docker-compose happy. Hope it will help someone else.